# Samza 0.14.1 not correctly handling OffsetOutOfRangeException exception?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-samza

We are facing an identical problem as described in this [thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@samza.apache.org/msg06740.html).

Here - Samza is requesting for an Kafka partition offset that is too old (i.e Kafka log has moved ahead). We are setting the property
`consumer.auto.offset.reset`
to `smallest` and therefore expecting that Samza will reset its checkpoint to earliest available partition offset in such a scenario. But that is not happening  we are getting exceptions of this form continually:

```
INFO [2018-08-21 19:26:20,924] [U:669,F:454,T:1,123,M:2,658]
kafka.producer.SyncProducer:[Logging_class:info:66] - [main] -
Disconnecting from vrni-platform-release:9092
INFO [2018-08-21 19:26:20,924] [U:669,F:454,T:1,123,M:2,658]
system.kafka.GetOffset:[Logging_class:info:63] - [main] - Validating offset
56443499 for topic and partition Topic3-0
WARN [2018-08-21 19:26:20,925] [U:669,F:454,T:1,123,M:2,658]
system.kafka.KafkaSystemConsumer:[Logging_class:warn:74] - [main] - While
refreshing brokers for Topic3-0:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.OffsetOutOfRangeException: The requested
offset is not within the range of offsets maintained by the server..
Retrying
```

Version Details

- Samza: 2.11-0.14.1
- Kafka Client: 1.1.0
- Kafka Server: 1.1.0 Scala 2.11

Browsing through the code, it appears that `GetOffset::isValidOffset` should be able to catch the exception `OffsetOutOfRangeException` and convert it to a false value. But it appears that this not happening. Could there be a mismatch in `package` of the `Exception`? [GetOffSet](https://github.com/apache/samza/blob/0.14.1/samza-kafka/src/main/scala/org/apache/samza/system/kafka/GetOffset.scala#L56) class is catching the
exception `import kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException`, but from logs, it appears that the package of this class is different. Could this be the reason?

```
def isValidOffset(consumer: DefaultFetchSimpleConsumer, topicAndPartition: TopicAndPartition, offset: String) = {
    info("Validating offset %s for topic and partition %s" format (offset, topicAndPartition))

    try {
      val messages = consumer.defaultFetch((topicAndPartition, offset.toLong))

      if (messages.hasError) {
        KafkaUtil.maybeThrowException(messages.error(topicAndPartition.topic, topicAndPartition.partition).exception())
      }

      info("Able to successfully read from offset %s for topic and partition %s. Using it to instantiate consumer." format (offset, topicAndPartition))

      true
    } catch {
      case e: OffsetOutOfRangeException => false
    }
}
```

Also, it Appears that [BrokerProxy](https://github.com/apache/samza/blob/0.14.1/samza-kafka/src/main/scala/org/apache/samza/system/kafka/BrokerProxy.scala#L85) class - the caller of `GetOffset` would print a log `"It appears that..."` in case it gets a false value, but it is not logging this line (indicating that some Exception generated in `GetOffset` method is going uncaught and being propagated up):

```
def addTopicPartition(tp: TopicAndPartition, nextOffset: Option[String]) = {
    debug("Adding new topic and partition %s to queue for %s" format (tp, host))

    if (nextOffsets.asJava.containsKey(tp)) {
      toss("Already consuming TopicPartition %s" format tp)
    }

    val offset = if (nextOffset.isDefined && offsetGetter.isValidOffset(simpleConsumer, tp, nextOffset.get)) {
      nextOffset
        .get
        .toLong
    } else {
      warn("It appears that we received an invalid or empty offset %s for %s. Attempting to use Kafka's auto.offset.reset setting. This can result in data loss if processing continues." format (nextOffset, tp))

      offsetGetter.getResetOffset(simpleConsumer, tp)
    }

    debug("Got offset %s for new topic and partition %s." format (offset, tp))

    nextOffsets += tp -> offset

    metrics.topicPartitions.get((host, port)).set(nextOffsets.size)
  }
```

Could this be due to mismatch in Kafka client library version that we are using? 
Is there a recommended Kafka client version we should use with Samza 0.14.1 (assuming that Kafka server is 1.x)?

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above is a bug in samza 0.14.0 and 0.14.1. [SAMZA-1822](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SAMZA-1822) is the bug id.

This is also discussed in the samza [mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/1fa014de0f57e31c877420b42df6d2fb9e2768492a9a2943d321c0e3@%3Cdev.samza.apache.org%3E).